# react native drawer navigator show on all screens

Tags: android, ios, react-native, navigation-drawer, stack-navigator

My drawer navigator does not open on all screens.

drawer nav:

```
import { DrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation"

const AppDrawerNavigator = new DrawerNavigator({
    Welcome: { screen: WelcomeScreen },
    JobList: { screen: JobListScreen }
},
    {
        drawerPosition: "right"
    })

export default AppDrawerNavigator;
```

Now, I actually want to show only 2 buttons in my drawer i.e. Logout & Reset. Do I need to have separate screens/components for this Logout and Reset ?
Also, I want to show the drawer on all the screens that I have, however, it gets opened/displayed only on my WelcomeScreen and JobListScreen.

StackNav (in index.js) :

```
const Navigator = StackNavigator({
    DrawerNavigator: { screen: DrawerNavigator },
    Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
    Tpo: { screen: TPOScreen },
    Welcome: { screen: WelcomeScreen },
    JobList: { screen: JobListScreen },
    JobDetails: { screen: JobDetailsScreen },
    JobOrdersList: { screen: JobOrdersListScreen }
})
```

If you see, the drawer does not get opened in other screens i.e. JobDetails , JobOrdersList, etc.

How do I show drawer on all the screens and with only two buttons rather than WelcomeScreen and JobListScreen ?

THanks.
Please bear with me as I am a newbie here on react native.

Comment: You know that "bare with me" means "get naked with me", right?

Answer (score 0):

**You need to set button on top right in page and that `onClick` of button you have to write code for open drawer**

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen');
```

Comment: I have a generic header which gets called for all pages & hambergerMenu/drawer via this header. But the problem is, to make this drawer work on all the screens, I need to add all the screens in my DrawerNavigator screens.

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote at the beginning, there are only two pages in the parameter object that you call the new DrawerNavigator, so the drawer is only displayed on WelcomeScreen and JobListScreen. If you want to display it all the screens, you need to use all the StackNavigator you created as a parameter to call the new DrawerNavigator method

```
import { DrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation"

  const AppDrawerNavigator = new DrawerNavigator({
   Home: { screen: Navigator },
   },
{
    drawerPosition: "right"
})

export default AppDrawerNavigator;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you elaborate it a little bit with some explanations?

Comment: As you wrote at the beginning, there are only two pages in the parameter object that you call the new DrawerNavigator, so the drawer is only displayed on WelcomeScreen and JobListScreen. If you want to display it all the screens, you need to use all the StackNavigator you created as a parameter to call the new DrawerNavigator method

Comment: I have just edited your answer with this information. Thanks

Comment: Hey, Where I put the above code for open drawer on each and every screen?